# Swift LocalNotificationで通知時間を指定したい

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

エラー内容
`cannot assign a value of type "NSDateFormatter" to a value of type` "NSDate"
エラー箇所
`notification.fireDate = myDateFormatter`

```
let myDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
myDateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ja_JP")
myDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm"

let mySelectedDate: NSString = myDateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
dateField.text = mySelectedDate as String


UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications();
let setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(setting)
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.fireDate = myDateFormatter
notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
notification.alertBody = "通知だよ"
notification.alertAction = "OK"
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification);
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/17983

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージの通りで、`myDateFormatter`は`NSDateFormatter`のインスタンスなので、`NSDate`ではないからですね。

`fireDate`に代入したいのは`sender.date`なのではありませんか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
代入したいのはsender.dateです。
下記、右辺にはどのように記載すればよろしいのでしょうか。
notification.fireDate =　
ご回答いただければありがたいです。

Comment: `sender.date`が`NSDate`のインスタンスなら`notification.fireDate = sender.date`でいいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！助かりました。